# Why does Setup Wizard transmit/receive data even long after the Android device has been set up?

Tags: google, privacy, xprivacy, setup-wizard

Even weeks after Android devices (tested on KitKat) have been set up, ***Setup Wizard*** still gets called frequently.

Using Xprivacy, it is clear that Setup Wizard frequently **connects to Google servers**.

What is it doing, and what data is it transmitting/receiving?